# How to perform a natural join on two tables using SQLAlchemy and Flask?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables Entry and Group defined in Python using Flask SQLAlchemy connected to a PostgresSQL database:

```
class Entry (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "entry"
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    group_title = db.Column('group_title', db.Unicode, db.ForeignKey('group.group_title'))
    url = db.Column('url', db.Unicode)
    next_entry_id = db.Column('next_entry_id', db.Integer,  db.ForeignKey('entry.id'))

    entry = db.relationship('Entry', foreign_keys=next_entry_id)
    group = db.relationship('Group', foreign_keys=group_title)

class Group (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "group"
    group_title = db.Column('group_title', db.Unicode, primary_key = True)
    group_start_id = db.Column('group_start_id', db.Integer)
    #etc.
```

I am trying to combine the two tables with a natural join using the `Entry.id` and `Group.group_start_id` as the common field.

I have been able to query a single table for all records. But I want to join tables by foreign key ID to give records relating `Group.group_start_id` and `Group.group_title` to a specific `Entry` record.

I am having trouble with the Flask-SQLAlchemy query syntax or process

I have tried several approaches (to list a few):

`db.session.query(Group, Entry.id).all()`

`db.session.query(Entry, Group).all()`

`db.session.query.join(Group).first()`

`db.session.query(Entry, Group).join(Group)`

All of them have returned a list of tuples that is bigger than expected and does not contain what I want. 
I am looking for the following result:
`(Entry.id, group_title, Group.group_start_id, Entry.url)`

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following query to perform a natuaral join for Group and Entry Table:
`db.session.query(Entry, Group).join(Group).filter(Group.group_start_id == Entry.id).order_by(Group.order.asc())`

I did this using the `.join` function in my query which allowed me to join the Group table to the Entry table. Then I filtering the results of the query by using the `Group.group_start_id` which is a foreign key in the Group table which referred to the `Entry.id` which is the primary key in the Entry table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already performed the basic join by using the [`relationship()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) call. 
We can focus on getting the data you want, a query such as `db.session.query(Entry, Group).all()` returns tuples of `(Entry, Group)` type, from this you can easily do something like:

```
test = db.session.query(Entry, Group).one()
print(test[0].id)             #prints entry.id
print(test[1].group_start_id) # prints Group.group_start_id
#...
```

SQLAlchemy has [great article](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html) on how joins work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, that isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Using the query tool in pgAdmin, I can use this query to get the table I'm looking for: `select * from "group" join "entry" on "group".group_start_id = "entry".id;`. How can I run this using the SQLAlchemy model system? I'm able to run the raw query via `db.engine.execute`, and I get the result I want, however it is a tuple and not dictionary style object as would be preferred.

Comment: Does the sample code I wrote not work? Or is there something else wrong with it?